# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting with Aorus RTX 2080

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

My pc boots ubuntu  18.04 perfectly when I use the integrated GPU. But when I try to boot it using the Aorus RTX 2080 it fails.

```
Error: "/dev/sda2: clean, 177761/files, 2422498/31127296 blocks"
```

and sometimes it says the grub file is missing. Tried to assign the path myself but says there is no such path.

Previously I had a Sapphire R9 390 GPU which also worked perfectly.

Specs:

- CPU: Core i7 4790K
- mobo: Gigabyte Z97x Gaming 3
- RAM: 16 GB Team Vulcan
- GPU: Gigabyte Aorus 2080

Answer (score 0):

I have Rtx 2080 ti, not encounter this problem but driver not detect either.
You should try to (remove the card, boot then) disable nouveau driver, then reboot and install Nvidia Driver.

First uninstall Nouveau video driver. Create a blacklist configuration file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

with the following contents:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Regenerate the kernel with initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and finally reboot machine:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutiom.. i found an easier solution i guess.. i just turned the intel integrated graphics off from bios settings.. and solved the issue